# Can TCC be modified to compile with Emscripten? If not, where can I find an x86-generating C compiler that does?

Tags: compiler-construction, posix, emscripten, ansi-c, tcc

After unzipping `tcc-0.9.26`, I edit configure to point at `emcc` instead of `gcc` and at `emar` instead of `ar`. Next, I uncomment the include of `ucontext` in `tcc.h` since it seems to be needed only for `tccrun`. Now I disable all the builtins (sub_ddmmss and so on) in `lib/libtcc1.c`, but I get an error because Emscripten tries to compile an assembly source file (an implementation of alloca), and I don't know how to get around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions implemented in assembly are much more fundamental, and are required by tcc. They are not optional in the sense you can remove them with a define or a comment. You can of course modify tcc itself not to use them, but you will have to provide your implementation of the functions you removed. So the only way to compile tcc with a non gcc/clang compiler is to significantly modify it or reimplement assembly functions.

Comment: Hmmm. I can't even get [CC500](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/edmund.grimley-evans/cc500/) or Bellard's otcc to work in Emscripten. I guess the best option would be to use jslinux/jsmodem and just pull out the binary after running tcc in the emulator.